# CAML Contains on a lookup field of a calculated column

Tags: lookup-column, calculated-column

I have some issue when using the CAML **Contains** statement when the field is a lookup field on a calculated column.

It basically does not work, the **Equal** works though.

here is the query, nothing special ...

```
   <Where>
      <Contains>
         <FieldRef Name='MyLookupOnACalculatedField' />
         <Value Type='Text'>some value</Value>
      </Contains>
   </Where>
```

Anybody else has the same issue ?

thanks

Comment: can you paste the code?

Comment: added to the original. This query works on a calculated field but does not work if this field is a lookup on a calculated field.

Comment: Wow, I just ran into the same issue. Have to tell them to not use a calculated field, not many other options